# Icons in windows 8 changed automatically

Tags: windows-8, icons

The icons of my folders in Windows 8 have changed automatically !

Now it is similar to that of the Unknown File Type icon.
My C: drive icon and some icons in the Explorer->Home menu had also changed, but they became normal after a restart. But the folder icons (Medium Size) don't change. This is also seen in the "Save Dialog"-box. Please help, Thanks in advance...

Here are the Images: (originals
[Image 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ro1m70zg0t1oalj/2013-10-24%2020_00_07-.png) ,
[Image 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cy2kbtrg3eueehv/2013-10-24%2020_01_01-Save%20As.png))

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your Icon-Cache became corrupted.

You can follow the instructions from [How to Rebuild the Icon Cache in Windows](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html).

Summarized below for your convenience:

---

**Option 1**

Automatically Rebuild the Icon Cache

1. Download the following batchfile. [Rebuild_Icon_Cache.bat](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/274775d1372780091-icon-cache-rebuild-rebuild_icon_cache.bat)
2. Save the file to your desktop, and run it.
3. Click/tap on <kbd>Run</kbd> when prompted.
4. Follow the instructions in the command prompt to rebuild the Icon Cache.
5. **Restart your computer** to generate a new `IconCache.db` file.
6. If the icons are still not displaying properly, then download and merge the **ICO** option in this tutorial for [Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html) or [Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8486-default-file-associations-restore-windows-8-a.html) to restore the default associations of .ico (icon) files.

---

**Option 2**

To Manually Rebuild the Icon Cache using the Command Prompt

1. Close and save anything that you are working on. This command will kill explorer and restart the computer when completed.
2. Open a command prompt in [Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/947-command-prompt.html) or [Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9702-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).
3. In the command prompt, Copy and paste each command line below exactly as is one at a time and press enter after each command.

   **WARNING**: The last command will restart the computer, so be sure to close and save anything that you are working on first.

   ```
   ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
   taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
   DEL "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /A
   shutdown /r /f /t 00
   ```
4. The **IconCache.db** file has now been rebuilt.
5. If the icons are still not displaying properly, then download and merge the **ICO** option in this tutorial for [Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html) or [Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8486-default-file-associations-restore-windows-8-a.html) to restore the default associations of .ico (icon) files.